# How to maintain equal space between two columns in html table?

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to display my output in table format but while displaying output column contents are unordered.

current output:

```
guru ok
moorthi  good
cont fine
```

required output

```
guru     ok
moorthi  good
cont     fine
```

What can I do do achieve in html table format?

my code:

```
<table cellspacing="10px" cellpadding="10px">
<tr>
<td>guru</td>
<td>ok</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>moorthi</td>
<td>good</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>cont</td>
<td>fine</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

sorry for simple question

Comment: Can you attach your code please?

Comment: @KillianSaintcricq check my updated question

Comment: no problem here http://jsfiddle.net/ubvhe5hj/ with your code...?

Answer (score 0):

> HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>guru</td>
    <td>ok</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>moorthi</td>
    <td>good</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cont</td>
    <td>fine</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> CSS:

```
table tr td{
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to have an issue with this, just add a property for the table in css, as so:

table style="table-layout:fixed;" cellspacing="10px" cellpadding="10px"

I think this will do the trick